# How to generate a digital certificate (for signing documents) if no validated authority exists in my country?

Tags: certificate, digital-signature

I want to generate a digital certificate for signature and authentication to sign a document, but I couldn't find any validated authority in my country that delivers digital certificates. In such a case, is there any way (website) to generate this type of certificates?
Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that If you digitally sign a document by using a digital certificate that you created, and not from an validated authority and then you share the digitally-signed file, other people cannot verify the authenticity of your digital signature without manually deciding to trust your self-signed certificate.

Comment: Well, how should your signatures be validated? I.e. who shall be able to validate your signatures with what software/services with how much specific configuration depending on your setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can create self signed certificate as described for example here [How to generate a self-signed SSL certificate using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl). Downside is that the Adobe Reader shows the signature invalid as by default it is not trusted.

You can also buy the "Document Signing Certificate" from any trust service provider. You will get USB crypto token with that. In this case Adobe Reader will show the signature valid.